# Possible bug: Reputation Change notification not resetting

Tags: bug

Every time I load or refresh one of the pages here at Stack Overflow, the green reputation notification turns on.

I click it, and it clears as normal.

When I navigate, or press F5, it returns.

At first I thought it was someone toggling their up vote on and off, but now there are `+20` showing across too questions.

Bug? Lag in the system somewhere from the tests earlier?

**Edit**

An upvote on another question came in, and the notification still shows only `+20` -- and points me to the older upvotes.

The current reputation counter on the same banner, however, is correct.

Comment: The same happens whenever you win/lose rep, the icon don't notify.